# How does mapDispatchToProps work in react-redux

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I watched the egghead.io tutorial on Redux and feel like I have some sense of what Redux is *trying* to do, but the way it actually works is still mysterious to me. I implemented Dan's simple counter app using the react-redux connect method, but I don't really understand my implementation. There are two possible ways I tried:

Without passing dispatch:

```
const mapDispatchToProps = {
  upIt: () => {
    return ({type:'INCREMENT'}
  )
  },
  downIt: () => {
    return({type:'DECREMENT'})
  }
}
```

Passing dispatch:

```
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  upIt: () => {
    dispatch({type:'INCREMENT'}
  )
  },
  downIt: () => {
    dispatch({type:'DECREMENT'})
  }
})
```

The counter works using either or those two options, but I am not sure how the first option (where I never call 'dispatch') manages to hook up to the store.dispatch method. Is there any reason I should prefer one way of writing the method over the other?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Think of `mapDispatchToProps` as an interface that passes relevant [**action creators**](http://redux.js.org/docs/basics/Actions.html#action-creators) to your component (these **action creators** appear on, and are accessed within your component as **props**).

**Action creators** are **NOT** the same as **actions**.

In Redux, an **action** is simply a plain JavaScript object such as the following (it can have whatever properties you want but must include the `type` property):

```
{ type: 'INCREMENT' }
```

These actions are sent to the **reducer**, which handles how to update the state based on the actions properties.

An **action creator** is a *function* that **sends these actions to the reducer** when called.

So, in your examples, `upIt` and `downIt` are **action creators**, while `{type:'INCREMENT'}` and `{type:'DECREMENT'}` are **actions**.

Take `upIt` for example:

```
upIt: () => {
    return ( {type:'INCREMENT'} )
}
```

The `connect()` function from `react-redux` will intercept the **action** returned from this **action creator** function, and dispatch it to the redux store (it will then be handled by the **reducer**).

`connect` function implementation:

```
connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(ComponentName)
```

However, consider the case where you might want to **dispatch multiple actions** from a single **action creator**. How would this be possible, when a function can only `return` a value once?

This is where the `dispatch` parameter of `mapDispatchToProps` comes in! It allows you to dispatch multiple **actions** from a single **action creator**.

For example, say you want to create a button in the UI to increment the counter, then 5 seconds later, decrement it again. Your **action creator** defined in `mapDispatchToProps` might look something like this:

```
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
    incrementForFiveSeconds: () => {
        dispatch( {type:'INCREMENT'} );
        setTimeout(() => { 
            dispatch( {type:'DECREMENT'} );
        }, 5000);
    },
    // other action creators
})
```

Notice how we can call the `dispatch` function twice within the same action creator!

To summarize:

1. If your *action creator* will only *dispatch* a **single action**, then you can use either the `return` or the `dispatch()` interface.
2. If your *action creator* may need to *dispatch* **multiple action creators**, then you will need to use the `dispatch()` interface.

Answer (score 4):

From the Redux documentation docs:

> [`mapDispatchToProps(dispatch, [ownProps]): dispatchProps`] (*Object*
>   or *Function*):
>
> If an object is passed, each function inside it is assumed to be a
>   Redux action creator. An object with the same function names, but with
>   every action creator wrapped into a `dispatch` call so they may be
>   invoked directly, will be merged into the component’s props. If a
>   function is passed, it will be given `dispatch`. If you don't want to
>   subscribe to store updates, pass `null` or `undefined` in place of
>   `mapStateToProps`. It’s up to you to return an object that somehow
>   uses `dispatch` to bind action creators in your own way. (Tip: you may
>   use the
>   [`bindActionCreators()`](http://reactjs.github.io/redux/docs/api/bindActionCreators.html)
>   helper from Redux.) If you omit it, the default implementation just
>   injects `dispatch` into your component’s props. If `ownProps` is
>   specified as a second argument, its value will be the props passed to
>   your component, and `mapDispatchToProps` will be re-invoked whenever
>   the component receives new props.

In the first case

```
const mapDispatchToProps = {
  upIt: () => {
    return ({type:'INCREMENT'}
  )
  },
  downIt: () => {
    return({type:'DECREMENT'})
  }
}
```

mapDispatchToProps is a object and thus `upIt` and `downIt` are assumed to be action creators.

In the second case:

```
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({

    upIt: () => {
        dispatch({type:'INCREMENT'}
      )
      },
      downIt: () => {
        dispatch({type:'DECREMENT'})
      }
    })
```

`mapDispatchToProps` is a function and thus each function inside it must be passed to dispatch